# Python Regular Expression Findall

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find up to the top level domain information.

If I were to search "https://testwebsite.com.au/folders/viewforum.php?f=1556n" I only want my expression to find "https://testwebsite.com.au"

I'm using the following expression:

```
urlRegex = re.compile(r'''( (https?|sftp|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?
           =~_|!:,.;'"*$()]*[a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]   )''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: maybe better use https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Comment: I would start with a html parser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be strict and correct, use a real URL parser.  If you're looking for something quick and dirty that will work for 99% of the URLs you'll find, how about:

```
urlRegex = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z]+://[^/\s]+)')
```